# Creating tables in Gtk

Tags: gtk, pygtk

I want to create tables like excel, that it have rows, have columns. But, when I search in internet, finding the Table as container.

How can i create tables in Gtk?

Comment: Have you looked at [`Gtk.Grid`](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout.html#grid)?

Comment: Like @nielsdg said, probably [GtkGrid](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN_MPJUQgPVpNTZk3PIi-Z5SiFNeUyj6Z) is what you need. Just give it a try.

Comment: Gtk.Grid is a container, i should to add css rules to it. I asked is there a specific widget for created creating tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Treeview container allows all excel like sheet functions like sorting, selecting, filtering etc.

[Treeview Tutorial](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/treeview.html)

Answer (score 1):

In GTK4, there is Gtk::ColumnView https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.ColumnView.html

I created a demo for using the column view here in rust, but the concepts may be portable to python https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs/pull/1111

Example screenshot

[image]